# Add sum below Each Nested Data tree for Tabulator table

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to implement Column sum for a nested table.
The docs show it for a simple table [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/column-calcs).
But, it doesn't work for Nested table.

I have tried including `bottomCalc:"sum"` in the column definition.

```
columns: [
{ title: "New Lead", field: "newLeadCount", width: 150, bottomCalc: "sum" },
],
```

I want to achieve the sum for each Major row group or Posting ID. But currently, it's showing sum at the bottom. And that too it's not able to count because of the incorrect method.
I tried this:
[image]

Comment: Please add working demo of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a custom calculator function to sum up the child values, with the caveat of needing to pass the field in as a param.

This code just nails the approach required https://jsfiddle.net/amwrfzt8/

This in the html

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

This in the script.

```
var tableDataNested = [
  {group:"Backend Engineer A", name:"Sourced", applied:300, screened:40, interviewed:5},
  {group:"Backend Engineer A", name:"Referred", applied:3, screened:1, interviewed:0},
  {group:"Backend Engineer A", name:"University", applied:4, screened:2, interviewed:1},
  {group:"Backend Engineer B", name:"Sourced", applied:1000, screened:140, interviewed:55},
  {group:"Backend Engineer B", name:"Referred", applied:30, screened:11, interviewed:2},
  {group:"Backend Engineer B", name:"University", applied:40, screened:22, interviewed:10},
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tableDataNested,
    dataTree:true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded:true,
    groupBy: "group",
    columns:[
      {title:"Name", field:"name", responsive:0},
      {title:"Applied", field:"applied", bottomCalc: "sum"},
      {title:"Screened", field:"screened", bottomCalc: "sum"},
      {title:"Interviewed", field:"interviewed", bottomCalc: "sum"},
    ],
});
```

Complete discussion over this is available at https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2235